# How to list a file by filename as a date?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rhel

I have list of filename which have format like this _ddmmyyyy.txt
for example :

```
filea_01122016.txt
filea_02122016.txt
filea_03122016.txt
filea_04122016.txt
filea_05122016.txt
```

And I want to compress those file from sysdate - 3 days in my RHEL environment. Assume today is 5 Dec 2016 and I want compress those file start from date 2 dec, 1 dec backward. Because the date that Im using is from the file name not the timestamp of file created(by system).

I read some tutorial that they are using `find` utility but in my case Im using date from the filename.

I already make some mechanism like this for compressing text in a whole month

```
dir=`date '+%Y%m%d'`

tanggal=`date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" '+%Y%m'`

base=/inf_shr/ProcessedSrc/CDC/ARCHIVE/F_ABC
cd $base

mkdir $dir
cp ../../F_CC/*${tanggal}* $dir

tar cvf - $dir | gzip -9 - > ${tanggal}_F_CC.tar.gz

rm -rf $dir
rm -rf ../../F_CC/*${tanggal}*
```

Now I want compress for file with sysdate - 3 days *)sorry for my english

And idea for the code? 
thank you

Comment: Slice, split, append, convert, join, and string. That's how I can think of doing it.

Comment: yeah dude. I just want to know the script like ls -lh that can listing like I mention above

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi all n thx for your advice. I already made listing like this for compressing file with format year and month

Here my code when I compress file for all txt which have year and month

dir=`date '+%Y%m%d'`

tanggal=`date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" '+%Y%m'`

base=/info_share/ProcessedSrc/CDC/ARCHIVE/F_CC
cd $base

mkdir $dir
cp ../../F_CC/*${tanggal}* $dir

tar cvf - $dir | gzip -9 - > ${tanggal}_F_CC.tar.gz

rm -rf $dir
rm -rf ../../F_CC/*${tanggal}*

Now I want compress for file with sysdate - 3 days *)sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** but below would be my approach

```
$ ls # listing the initial content
filea_17122016.txt  filea_19122016.txt  filea_21122016.txt
filea_18122016.txt  filea_20122016.txt  script.sh
$ cat script.sh  # Ok, here is the script I wrote
#!/bin/bash
now="$(date +%s)"
for file in filea_*
# Mind, if recursive globbing required put ** instead of *
# after you do set -s globstar
do
  date=${file#filea_}
  date=${date%.txt}
  y=$(cut -b 5- <<<"$date") # We use cut to trim year month and date separately
  m=$(cut -b 3-4 <<<"$date")
  d=$(cut -b 1-2 <<<"$date")
  date=$(date -d "$y-$m-$d" +%s) # Calulating the time in seconds from epoch, using the date string where we use the above calculated values
  dif=$(( (now-date)/(3600*24) )) #Calculating the difference in dates
  if [ "0$dif" -ge 3 ]
  then
    zip mybackup.zip "$file" #If the file is 3 or more days old, the add it to zip
    #Note if the zip file already exists, files will be appended
    rm "$file" # remove the file
  fi
done
$ ./script.sh # Script doing its job
  adding: filea_17122016.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: filea_18122016.txt (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l mybackup.zip  #listing the contents of the zip file
Archive:  mybackup.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2016-12-21 11:38   filea_17122016.txt
        0  2016-12-21 11:38   filea_18122016.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
$ ls # listing the left over content, which includes the newly created zip
filea_19122016.txt  filea_21122016.txt  script.sh
filea_20122016.txt  mybackup.zip
$ # Job done
```

Comment: HI @sjsam  thank you for your respond. I will try to implement your code and back with the result soon! many thanks

Comment: @BlackRabbit1703 : You're welcome,do accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: heeyy Capt @sjsam ! you save my day dude! many thanks for you capt!

Comment: @ admiral @BlackRabbit1703 : You rock ! seasons greetings in advance. Don't forget to collect a few hats on SO winterbash.